# When using "file mkdir" in TCL i get the error that the folder does not exist, but thats why i want to create it..

Tags: tcl, mkdir

I am having a little trouble when creating a directory in TCL8.5.9 on a Windows 7 Computer.

```
set CurrentDir          [ file dirname $GUI_DB_path]
set ImageFolderPath     [ file join $CurrentDir "DeflectionPlots" ]
# Always try to delete the Folder no matter if it exists or not
file delete -force      $ImageFolderPath

# sometimes the following throws an error. Do not understand why.
# Create a clean and empty ImageFolder
file mkdir              $ImageFolderPath
```

Sometimes, but not always i get the error:

cant't create directory.....$ImageFolderPath.....  No such file or Directory

Well, that is why I want to create it. Running the code a second time without any changes results in the creation of the Directory as desired. What causes this and how can i resolve the issue? I could catch the error, but then I still would not have my Folder created.

Comment: Are you shure that `CurrentDir` exists at the time you want to create the `ImageFolderPath` directory?

Comment: Yes, I am shure.

Comment: Are you always executing the script (e.g., using `tclsh`) from the same working directory? Is `CurrentDir` an absolute path fragment? Make sure that it is absolute at all times, by e.g. writing `set ImageFolderPath [file normalize [file join $CurrentDir "DeflectionPlots"]]`

Comment: I'd try some 'puts debugging': `puts "CurrentDir=$CurrentDir\nImageFolderPath=$ImageFolderPath\npwd=[pwd]\n[glob -directory $CurrentDir *]"` to learn what Tcl "sees"

Comment: The times i checked the path was absolute. I did now however use the normalize Option as sugested by mrcalvin. The error did not Show upp again yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows file operations (or their internal locking) is often slow.

I run into problems like yours where deletions/new files/renames take 
a while and then I get errors because the file(s) are in some sort of 
operating system limbo.

You can add a short sleep between the delete and the create and that
should resolve the issue on Windows.

```
set ::img_create_sleep 0
after 200 [list set ::img_create_sleep 1]
vwait ::img_create_sleep
```

Comment: This half-state is often due to antivirus software scanning activity, as that both takes a while and is done at a privilege level that makes it invisible to user code other than via its weird effects on file operations.